# Order comfirmation email is not sent to customer Magento 2.1.0?

Tags: order-email, transactional-mail, magento2.1.0, order-confirmation

Order confirmation emails not working in magento 2.1.0, I have seen a message in admin order view page:

> Order # 8000001098 (The order confirmation email is not sent)

Other transactional emails are working except order confirmation email.

ALso, I have checked

> Asynchronous sending is disabled
>
> Disable Email Communications is set to No

But still it is not working.

Check screenshot: http://nimb.ws/AUnR1c

What is the issue?

Comment: Are you working on live ?

Comment: Yes. Also, I have checked on demo site.

Comment: Have you fixed that?